# problemas em adicionar um elemento na HTML com JSON

Tags: json

```
var componente = {

    HTML :'<div class="alert" style="background-color:#951f2c !important;">' +
    '<input type="text" class="form-control titulo-valor" placeholder="Digite o Título do Bloco" style="background-color:#951f2c !important; color: white !important; border:none !important;"/>'+
    '</div>'
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").on("click",function(){
        var componenteAtual = $(this).data("componente");

        $(".resultado").html(componente.componenteAtual);    
    });    
});
```

Estou tentando adicionar elementos na html dinamicamente usando JSON com várias tags dentro. Não está funcionando, dei um alert no `componente.componenteAtual` e ele está retornando `undefined` como resultado. 
Se eu escrever `componente.HTML` funciona...

Abaixo há o jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vxq92vzw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acerder a propriedades de objetos de maneira dinâmica tens de usar parentesis retos, ou seja:

```
componente['nome da propriedade aqui']
```

Quando usas `.html(componente.componenteAtual);` isso vai procurar uma propriedade chamada `componenteAtual` no objeto, mas ela não existe. O que deves fazer é

```
.html(componente[componenteAtual]);
```

pois dessa maneira `componenteAtual` é convertido no valor que guarda (`HTML`) e na prática fica:

```
.html(componente['HTML']);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lr033bna/